# Writing a procedure in python that finds primes in a list, and stores them in an empty list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, primes

I am currently having some issues doing this assignment from my class:

"Write a procedure primes_only(input_list,prime_list) that takes two lists as its parameters, an input_list of numbers and an empty list called prime_list. The procedure must examine each number in list input_list. If the number is a prime number it should add a copy of that number to the prime-list. You MUST use the functions you wrote before to do most of the work for you."

Here's what i've tried to do so far:

```
input_list = int(input())
prime_list = []

def primes_only(input_list,prime_list):
    for x in range(2,input_list):
        if(input_list%x)==0:
            prime_list.append(x)
        else:
print(prime_list)

    def is_prime(n):
    if (n==1):
        return False
    elif (n==2):
        return True;
    else:
        for x in range(2,n):
            if(n % x==0):
                return False
        return True
```

Will someone please help?

Comment: What's your question? Please ask a specific question. "Will someone help me write this program" is off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what's in your syllabus and what you are allowed to use and what you arent,
so I have written a very simple one.
I have described what I have done in the program using comments(statements followed by the # sign).
And I have kept the is_prime function unchanged.(Though you can do it in a much fancier way as Javier has said)
And another thing the numbers given as input must be separated by commas, and must be entered at once.

Here's the code:

```
def is_prime(n):
    if (n==1):
        return False
    elif (n==2):
        return True;
    else:
        for x in range(2,n):
            if(n % x==0):
                return False
        return True

def primes_only(input_list, prime_list):
    # Iterates over each number and checks whether the
    # number is prime or not, if so then it is appended
    # to the prime list
    for n in input_list:
        # Check if the number is prime and whether it
        # has already been entered into the list.
        # This checks that the same element is not appended
        # twice
        if is_prime(n) and prime_list.count(n) == 0:
            prime_list.append(n)

# Take input from the user with numbers separated by commas
# and split the input into numbers in the form of a string 
input_list = input("Enter the elments->").split(",")

# Convert the numbers from string to int
for i in range(len(input_list)):
    input_list[i] = int(input_list[i])

prime_list = []
primes_only(input_list, prime_list)
print(prime_list)
```

Sample Input and Output:

```
Enter the elments->1,5,3,2,4,7,3,19
[5, 3, 2, 7, 19]
```

Answer (score 0):

The description of the problem suggests that two things are going on at once:

1. Detect if a number is prime.
2. Copy the number to the other list.

In that case, I'd write two functions: `is_prime` and your `primes_only`.

```py
def is_prime(n: int) -> bool:
    """Returns whether the given number is prime."""
    assert n > 1, 'The number must be greater than 1'

    for i in range(2, n):  # Could use square root of n as the upper bound.
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

This function should be easy enough to test manually on a REPL or, even better, create some test cases.

Then:

```py
def primes_only(nums: Iterable[int], primes: List[int]) -> None:
    for n in nums:
        if is_prime(n):
            primes.append(n)
```

A fancier version:

```py
def primes_only(nums: Iterable[int], primes: List[int]) -> None:
    primes.extend(n for n in nums if is_prime(n))
```

(I did not test the code)

Comment: The formatting confused me. You actually wrote these two functions too. Well done!